# Get Gmail Inbox feed Google.Apis C# .NET

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I need to read the gmail inbox feed using Oauth2.0. Simulating in the postman,

```
Auth URL : https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
Access Token URL : https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
Client ID : XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com
Client Secret : XXXXX
Scope : https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom
GrantType: Authorization Code
```

I requested the token and used it on the header

`Authorization - Bearer XXXXXXXXXX.`

And I made the request via GET right in my scope and got my email feeds. Works!!!

The postman generates a code in C #, but the token expires.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("postman-token", "d48cac24-bd3e-07b5-c616-XXXXXXXX");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer ya29.a0AfH6SMDZlUmw0xLHAoYIJuIfTkXXXXXXXXQSPP17GmXT26fJEfWB9w8UiwQ2YF32-nOp6zY9H_lwJEEXXXXXXXXXXXYK4e0tcZkieGbBl5Eow2M-7Gxp20kfDtXXXXXVjiXymLXyMkYEI");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

I'm trying to do it via Google.Api, using GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow and already using token refresh.

With the code below, I got authorization from the application, but I can't read the xml atom feed

```
            GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow;
            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var clientfile = @"client_secrets.json";

            using (var stream = new FileStream(clientfile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                {
                    DataStore = new FileDataStore("StoreTest"),
                    ClientSecretsStream = stream,
                    Scopes = new[] { "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/" }
                });
            }

            var uri = Request.Url.ToString();
            var code = Request["code"];
            if (code != null)
            {
                var token = flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync(UserId, code,
                    uri.Substring(0, uri.IndexOf("?")), CancellationToken.None).Result;

                // Extract the right state.
                var oauthState = AuthWebUtility.ExtracRedirectFromState(
                    flow.DataStore, UserId, Request["state"]).Result;
                Response.Redirect(oauthState);
            }
            else
            {
                var result = new AuthorizationCodeWebApp(flow, uri, uri).AuthorizeAsync(UserId,
                    CancellationToken.None).Result;
                if (result.RedirectUri != null)
                {
                    // Redirect the user to the authorization server.
                    Response.Redirect(result.RedirectUri);
                }
                else
                {
                    // The data store contains the user credential, so the user has been already authenticated.
                    
                   var gmailfeed = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                    {
                        HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential,
                        ApplicationName = "GetFeed",
                        
                    });

                    var inboxlistRequest = gmailfeed.Users.Messages.List("me");
                    inboxlistRequest.LabelIds = "Label_19780355190759038";
                    inboxlistRequest.IncludeSpamTrash = false;
                    var emailListResponse = inboxlistRequest.Execute();

                    foreach (var mail in emailListResponse.Messages)
                    {
                        var mailId = mail.Id;
                        var threadId = mail.ThreadId;
                     
                        Message message = gmailfeed.Users.Messages.Get("me", mailId).Execute();
                        Console.WriteLine((message.Snippet));
                    }

                }
            }
```

I got to read the email, but I need the xml atom feed.

Could someone help me how I make this call to get the atom feed, using the granted token. If there is an easier way to do it too, it would be cool to share.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Resolved using respsharp, restclient!!

tks